# CANVAS - JS - Rounded and smooth path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm working on a canvas app, with html and js/jquery.
But i have a problem with the path, it's not rounded, too much aliasing.
Here is the fiddle so you can understand my problem. And right after the code.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yebqwwzm/)

```js
var $canvas = $("#mainCanvas");
var context = $canvas[0].getContext("2d");
/* ------ CANVAS ------ */

//On mouse events on the canvas:
$canvas.mousedown(function(e) {
//On mousedown, storing the starting coordinates and enable the drawing.
lastEvent = e; //saving the starting coordinates
mouseDown = true; //drawing enabled
}).mousemove(function(e) {
//On mousemove draws the path, change the style, stroke the line, update the coordinates.
if (mouseDown) {
context.beginPath(); //begin the path
context.moveTo(lastEvent.offsetX, lastEvent.offsetY); //starting coordinates
context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
context.lineWidth = $("#thickness").val();
context.strokeStyle = color;  //color of path
context.stroke(); //draw the path
lastEvent = e; //replacing the coordinates
}
}).mouseup(function() {
//On mouseup drawing disabled
mouseDown = false;
}).mouseleave(function(){
//If the mouse leaves the canvas, stop drawing. BUG FIXING
$canvas.mouseup();
});
```

## Solution

```js
context.lineCap = 'round';
```

*Special thanks to Stacey Burns*

Comment: What do you mean by aliased ? Could you also provide a mockup (a still image) with what the issue is and what the expected result is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is coming from the lineCap attribute. Set it round and you will get a smooth path:

```
context.lineCap = 'round';
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/632qeo58/)

Comment: Thank you!!!!! This is what I was looking for! Edited the answer with your solution!